# Add custom property to magento Attributes and display it on the front end

Tags: magento

I have started using magento as my ecommerce cms and I know that is an extremely powerful platform.
Recently I came across its functionality that helps the developer extending the core and I have managed to add custom category options.
Is there any chance to achieve the same results on an attribute?
I would like to add a text description on the properties' tab and display it on the front end?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is possible with writing your own custom module. I did it to add a tooltip-option to an attribute.

You can use the `adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute_edit_prepare_form`-event to add a field with your observer:

```
$fieldset = $observer->getForm()->getElement('base_fieldset');
$fieldset->addField('tooltip', 'text', array(
    'name' => 'tooltip',
    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Tooltip'),
    'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Tooltip')
));
```

This adds the extra field to the attribute-edit screen. Next up is to make sure the property gets saved when editing your attribute. This can be done in your installer script with something like:

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('catalog/eav_attribute'),
    'tooltip',
    array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'nullable'  => true,
        'comment'   => 'Tooltip'
    )
);
```

You also have to make sure your `Model/Resource/Setup`-class extends `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` instead of `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`.

Now, at this point, you can save your custom attribute property. Next step is to display it on the frontend. This can be done fairly easy, just by simple Magento templating 101:

For example, in `catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` in the `foreach()`-loop, place something like this, to display the tooltip:

```
echo $_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getTooltip();
```

That's nice...

**Update:** Since I got some questions about this subject by e-mail, I decided to write a more detailed blog post about it. You can read it here: http://gielberkers.com/add-custom-properties-magento-attributes/

Comment: The above link provides very good detailed information about the solution but its not working in some versions of magento. So to overcome this issue, just Add the code provided in the Step 3  outside the global -scope in your config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2
(Adding simple Yes/No property for product attributes).

It could be used ui_component "product_attribute_add_form.xml" (example could be find in vendor modules)

*OR if it is not working*:

1. Create a new module Vendor_ModuleName. Extend "catalog_eav_attribute" and add new column in **Vendor/ModuleName/etc/db_schema.xml** (don't forget to generate db_schema_whitelist.json)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="catalog_eav_attribute">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="new_column" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false"
                identity="false" default="0" comment="Comment for new_column"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

2. Subscribe on event in **Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**
   "product_attribute_form_build_main_tab" - if you want to put a new property in main tab (base_fieldset)
   "product_attribute_form_build" - if you want to put a new property in advanced tab (advanced_fieldset)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="product_attribute_form_build">
        <observer
            name="vendor_modulename_observer_backend_product_attributeformbuild"
            instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Backend\Product\AttributeFormBuild"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

3. Create an observer Vendor/ModuleName/Observer/Backend/Product/AttributeFormBuild.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Backend\Product;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager;
use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno;

class AttributeFormBuild implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected Yesno $yesNo;
    protected $moduleManager;

    /**
     * @param Manager $moduleManager
     * @param Yesno $yesNo
     */
    public function __construct(
        Manager $moduleManager,
        Yesno $yesNo
    )
    {
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        $this->yesNo = $yesNo;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        if (!$this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Vendor_ModuleName')) {
            return;
        }

        $form = $observer->getForm();

//        $fieldset = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');

        $fieldset = $form->getElement('advanced_fieldset');
        $yesnoSource = $this->yesNo->toOptionArray();
        $fieldset->addField(
            'new_column',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'new_column',
                'label' => __('New column label'),
                'title' => __('New column title'),
                'note' => __('Use this attribute for something'),
                'values' => $yesnoSource,
                'required' => false,
            ],
            'is_filterable'
        );
    }
}
```