# Add custom description to magento Attributes and display it on the front end

Tags: magento

I have a site where I added some custom attributes and displayed in the frontend. Now I want add a description of the attributes and display it in the frontend in a tooltip or whatever.
I have checked this reference 
 [Add custom property to magento Attributes and display it on the front end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959299/add-custom-property-to-magento-attributes-and-display-it-on-the-front-end) on stackoverflow. But its not clear in which particular page I have to use it. **I don't want to use any plugin.** Please refer me a solution with custom code.

Answer (score 0):

When you Add a Custom Attribute to the products, it will stored in to the Magento system as EAV attribute. So you must look into the EAV structure. When you look into the table "eav_attribute" you can understand how the attributes are stored.

So, if you want to Add and manage the Tooltip Description for the Attributes, You must add one more column to the "eav_attribute" table. for this you must create a custom module to override the Magento core eav functionalities. By following the above link you can create the tooltip Description text for the attributes.